# How to get ajax value and store in PHP variable?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

**custom.js** file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#company_name").keyup(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/capms_v2/ca_autocomplete/getcompanyName",
            data: {
                keyword: $("#company_name").val()
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                //alert(data);
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $('#DropdownCompany').empty();
                    $('#company_name').attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                    $('#DropdownCompany').dropdown('toggle');

                } else if (data.length == 0) {
                    $('#company_name').attr("data-toggle", "");
                }
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    if (data.length >= 0)
                        $('#DropdownCompany').append('<li role="displayCountries" ><a role="menuitem DropdownCompany" id=' + value['company_id'] + ' Address1=' + value['company_address1'] + ' Address2=' + value['company_address2'] + ' city=' + value['company_city'] + ' state=' + value['company_state'] + ' pincode=' + value['company_zip'] + '  class="dropdownlivalue">' +
                            value['company_name'] + '</a></li>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
    $('ul.txtcountry').on('click', 'li a', function() {
        $('#company_name').val($(this).text());
        $('#company_id').val($(this).attr("id"));
        // $('#company_address1').val($(this).text());

        $('#tableCityID').html($(this).attr("id"));
        $('#tableCityName').html($(this).text());
        $('#Address1').html($(this).attr("Address1"));
        $('#Address2').html($(this).attr("Address2"));
        $('#city').html($(this).attr("city"));
        $('#state').html($(this).attr("state"));
        $('#pincode').html($(this).attr("pincode"));
    });
});
```

I was getting id in `span id="tableCityID"` but if I store the value and pass the value to mysql it was not fetching the value

```
$com = '<span id="tableCityID">';
```

and if I echo the select query

```
echo $sql="select * from ca_job WHERE job_status!='Closed' AND job_customer_name = '".$com."'";
```

I get the result with not completed single codes

```
select * from ca_job WHERE job_status!='Closed' AND job_customer_name = '15
```

If anybody faces this problem, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

just use the `</span>`

like this

`$com = '<span id="tableCityID"></span>';`

Comment: thank you rajesh now it was coming with single codes ' ' but not fetching the value

Comment: We cannot do it dynamically because php is pre-processor so we need to make another ajax or jquery call where we need to pass tableCityID by get or post method and we have to write the query there and use it